# Migration of tx_news from one TYPO3 to another

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

I want to migrate existing news from one instance to another one incl. relations to FAL and content elements.

What is the best practise? I tried T3D Export, but it needs too much memory. Is this the only solution or do you have better ones?

Answer (score 0):

1st you can try to export smaller chunks.

2nd you can do the export by hand. But then you must know which records are involved and what files are involved. And you must handle uid-collisions!

Starting with a simple query for your news-records.
Then you need all related records: FAL, tt_content, categories
Depending on your tt_content records you might need further related records - typical: FAL
Then you need to identify all the files.
Before you import all the records: make sure the used uids are unused in your target installation. oherwise you need to modify your uids (e.g.: you can add a constant value of 10000 to all your uids)